# Switching between Trusted mode and Restricted mode in VS code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am opening my VS code, and it is opening in restricted mode every time I open it. I don't want to disable restricted mode but want to turn it off for the moment and get back to the normal mode. How to turn off and on the restricted mode and switch between the two modes easily?

I have got a solution online, but they show how to disable restricted mode permanently.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening code via a command line you can use

```
code --disable-workspace-trust .
```

This will open the current folder with Workspace Trust disabled. (Replace . with the folder you want to open)

This disables Workspace Trust for the current session(instance) only.